# code keeps running without proper sequence

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, datetimepicker, timepicker

In my code i have a date and time picker.... but for some reason the code doesn't wait till i pick anything and once the mDateSetListener dialog is shown the Log.d shows in the Logcat today's date.
also the first time the dialog is shown, it doesn't show mTimeSetListener, and i have to request it for a second time for it to work properly
here is my code

```
static void dateAndTimePicker(final Context context, final ListView selectedFood, final int type) {

    contextGlobal = context;
    dateTime = new int[5];
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(contextGlobal,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1; /*january is 0 (months start with 0 not 1)*/
            Log.d("date is", month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
            dateTime[0] = year;
            dateTime[1] = month;
            dateTime[2] = day;
            hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(contextGlobal,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }

    };

    mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
            Log.d("Time is", hour + ":" + minute);
            dateTime[3] = hour;
            dateTime[4] = minute;
            addFood(contextGlobal, dateTime, selectedFood, type);

        }
    };

    Log.d("date", String.valueOf(day));

}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but for some reason, the code doesn't wait till I pick anything and once the mDateSetListener dialog is shown the Log.d shows in the Logcat today's date.

It's because,  `onDateSet` is some sort of asynchronous call (waits for the user to perform an action), and will only be triggered when a user taps the desired date form `DatePickerDialog`

> also the first time the dialog is shown, it doesn't show mTimeSetListener, and I have to request it for a second time for it to work properly

--   --  --

Comment: thats the point..... the code runs the Log.d before i pick a date...... and the first time i pick a date..... timePickerDialog doesnt run and i have to run the datePickerDialog again for it to work properly

Comment: The CODE WILL RUN Log.d BEFORE you'll pick the date, as explained in the answer

Comment: so how can i program in to work differently (if possible)

Comment: If you want to print the value of day after user has selected the date, move the line of code inside `onDateSet()`

Comment: its not just printing.... i want the code to stop until the selections are done, because whats after that pick (which i didnt include) depend on the date picked

Comment: That's not possible, as I mentioned, `onDateSet()` is some sort of **ASYNCHRONOUS CALL** and is triggered only when user itself performs an action.

Comment: Yeah, no problem! I'm glad I covered your doubt. I'm sorry I couldn't answer next question, the code seems right to me, I guess there must be some other problem.